# How to refresh Power Apps form after updates in SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I'm new in Power Apps, and building a small application which is connected with the backend SharePoint list. The issue is, that whenever I change something in the list (like changing the type of column from sing line text to Choice), then the Power Apps form does not get these updates. Even if refresh the data source in the Power App designer, the form keeps showing the error of wrong control.

Any solution to this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove the field from the form and then re-add it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/add-form

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the data source first
[image]

And then delete the previous fields according to this operation.

[image]

Finally add it back

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can refresh the data source as show in blow screen [image]